# How to loop over a parameter list and submit jobs?

Tags: bash, qsub, do-loops

I have a job that has an input and I want to loop over a list of parameters while submitting the job. Here is the part of my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
errors=$HOME/ERRORS/convergence/GvsE/B_2/error.log
count=`qstat | wc -l`
gi=( "0" "0.25" "0.5" "1" "2" )
Ener=( "1" "2" "5" "10" "20" "21" "22" "23" "24" "25" )

for ((i=0; i < ${#g[@]}; i++)); do
        for ((j=0; j < ${#E[@]}; j++)); do
                qsub -o $errors -e $errors -v E=${#Ener[$j]},slices=${200},modes=${60},g=${#gi[$i]} job_convcheck.sh
                count=`expr $count + 1`
                while [ $count -gt 4950 ]
                do
                  sleep 420
                  count=`qstat | wc -l`
                done
        done
done
```

When I run this I am neither get an answer nor a result. What is wrong with that?

Comment: Try to quote your arguments properly around `""` to prevent word splitting and pathname expansion. See [Word Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) and [Pathname/Filename Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-pathname-expansion)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the obvious is

```
for ((i=0; i < ${#g[@]}; i++)); do
```

should be

```
for ((i=0; i < ${#gi[@]}; i++)); do
```

and

```
for ((j=0; j < ${#E[@]}; j++)); do
```

should be

```
for ((j=0; j < ${#Ener[@]}; j++)); do
```

**Or** if you want the indices simply do:

```
for i in "${!gi[@]}"; do
    for j in "${!Ener[@]}"; do
```